# Есть данные в массиве как вынуть первую запись например "uid"?

Tags: массивы, php

Есть данные в массиве как вынуть первую запись например "uid" вот данные.

```
object(stdClass) (1) {
    ["response"] => array(1) {
        [0] => object(stdClass) (4) {
            ["uid"]=> int(118830222) ["first_name"]=> string(12) "Никита" ["last_name"]=> string(14) "Потехин" ["photo_100"]=> string(47) "http://cs301309.vk.me/u118830222/d_02a3e436.jpg" } } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$friend_info = json_decode(file_get_contents('твой api запрос вконтакте'), true);
$uiduser = $friend_info['response'][0]['uid']; //uid
```